# Laravel save many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_categories');
}
```

Controller

```
public $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1;
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $titles = $request->PostTitle;
    $post = new Post();
    $post->PostTitle = $titles[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE];
    $post->save();
    $post->categories()->attach($request->categoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]);
    unset($titles[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]);
    foreach ($titles as $key => $title) {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle[$key];
        $post->save();
        $post->categories()->attach($request->categoryID[$key]);
    }

    return response()->json($post);
```

View

```
<select class="form-control category-list" name="categoryID[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Pilih Kategori">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
            {{ $category->CategoryName }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

If I have two categories and I want to select all the categories, why I only get the last category? I also tried to use foreach, but I got error offset.
Any idea?

I have two tab pane..
I store two categoryID in tab 1 and one categoryID in tab 2.. then I click on submit button.. the header response two categoryID in tab 1, but in my database, I only got the last record

- PostTitle[1]:sadasd
- categoryID[1]:1
- categoryID[1]:2
- PostTitle[2]:asdasd
- categoryID[2]:1

When I console, it shows two CategoryID..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBl2B.png

Comment: Is it a typo ? `BelongsToMany` should be `belongsToMany`

Comment: you may want to use sync() instead of attach();

Comment: how did you get `$categories` in the view ??

Comment: @linktoahref that's same.. I changed into belongsToMany, and I still only get the last record..

Comment: @Maraboc I put $categories = Category::all(); in create controller

Comment: can you do `$categories = Category::all(); dd($categories);` and tel us what you get ?

Comment: @Demonyowh nothing changed.. still get the last record

Comment: Please can you show the controller method that is returns the view?

Comment: @RossWilson I am using store in my controller, you can see it right now. I have changed it..

Comment: had you checked the value stored in request ?

Comment: @Demonyowh I'm using dd(count($request->categoryID));.. but it returns 1.. I don't know why.. but In my view, I choose 2 categoryID

Comment: is this ajax or normal form submission ?

Comment: @Demonyowh ajax.. I am confuse, why count = 1? I think if I select 2 category ID, my count = 2, why I got 1

Comment: before ajax try to console.log the value of the category variable ..

Comment: @Demonyowh when I click submit, I got headers like this.. (look at my question)

Comment: @jamesriady Please try to use `dd($request->input('categoryID'))`, lets see what you'll get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution..
I only need to change the view

```
<select class="form-control category-list" name="categoryID[{{$language->id}}][]" multiple data-placeholder="Pilih Kategori">
  @foreach($categories as $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->CategoryName}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

and also change the controller

```
$post->categories()->attach($request->categoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]);
```

Comment: great finally you got what you want

Answer (score 1):

For what are you using this model, what's it's name?
Typically it's done that way:
App\Category:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_categories');
}
```

App\Post:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories');
}
```

The two relationships are not in the same file, but in the two seperate models which are connected.

Comment: I separate the file in my project

Comment: OKay try finding the category first and then attach it
like this:
`$category = Category::find($request->categoryID);` and then `$post->categories()->attach($category);`

Comment: I got only the last record

Answer (score 1):

**Attaching / Detaching**

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships)

> Eloquent also provides a few additional helper methods to make working
>   with related models more convenient. For example, let's imagine a user
>   can have many roles and a role can have many users. To attach a role
>   to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins
>   the models, use the attach method:

You are passing only one value in attach and thus getting only the last record in order to get all you need to pass all categoryID

```
public $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1;
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $titles = $request->PostTitle;
    $post = new Post();
    $post->PostTitle = $titles[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE];
    $post->save();
    $post->categories()->attach($request->categoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]);
    unset($titles[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]);
    $data= array();
    foreach ($titles as $key => $title) {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->PostTitle = $request->PostTitle[$key];
        $post->save();
        $data[]= $post->categories()->attach($request->categoryID[$key]);
    }

    return response()->json($data);
```

`

Comment: I have followed your way, but still same.. It only get the last record.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: like I post, CategoryID[1] = 1, CategoryID[1] = 2.. In database, I only get 2.. I think that the first value is overwrite by last value.

Comment: use `print_r($title)` or `dd()` to check what you have in your array it will clear your doubt that the first value is overwriting by last value or not

Comment: dd($title); I got the value of $title

Comment: ok and did you checked `print_r($title)` are you getting both values or just the last value??

Comment: I am trying to use the way like this..
public $DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 1;
$category = $request->categorID($this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
print_r($category);

when I choose two categoryID, it returns 2. If I choose one categoryID, it returns 1.

Comment: ok bro you are getting the value because you have inserted the record and thus it is returning the last inserted record I'm not wrong

Comment: I don't understand why array($request->categoryID[$this->DEFAULT_LANGUAGE]); only return the last record? can you explain to me?

Comment: you are only passing the single id you need to pass ids if I went somewhere wrong the enlighten me :)

Comment: Please accept the answer to close the question https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this one bro. 
I just change your code in controller.
I wish it can help you :)

Model

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Category', 'post_categories');
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_categories');
}
```

Controller

```
$post = App\Post::findOrFail($id);
$post = $post->load('categories');
$attributes = $post->attributes->toArray();
```

View

```
<select class="form-control category-list" name="categoryID[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Pilih Kategori">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
            {{ $category->CategoryName }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I got this error "Call to a member function toArray() on null"

Comment: Please check I edited my answer, look at the codes in controller

Comment: why using find? if I'm using $post = App\Post::findOrFail($id);, How about my $post = new Post();?.. I want to store data in post table too

Answer (score 0):

in your view, try to change multiple="multiple" to just multiple

Comment: The problem is not with the select box in view. He can not get all the categories base on what he did.

Comment: @MortezaRajabi yap

Comment: he can't get all categories because only last selected category passed to request, it's commonly because the view not sent them correctly